# ASP Menu control not aligning

Tags: c#, css, asp.net

I'm having issues centering an ASP menu, it is 100% of the time aligning to the left of the window.  I have it enclosed in a Div, and then nested in another Div.

I can get it to align right if I have the nested Div to `float:right`.  I've been reading on including `!important` to override some styles from other divs that may be causing this `Header` div to not align properly.

```
CSS
body {
}
#Header
{

    width: 100%;
    height: 40px;
    font-family: Calibri;
    text-align:center !important;

}
#LeftColumn
{
    font-family: Verdana;
    font-size: small;
    text-align: left;
    float: left;
    padding-top: 20px;
    padding-left: 2%;
    width: 19%;
    height: 250px;
}
#MainContent
{
    font-family: Verdana;
    font-size: medium;
    padding-top: 20px;
    width: 79%;
    height: 250px;
    float: right;
    text-align: center;
    position: relative;
}
#Footer
{
    font-family: Verdana;
    font-size: x-small;
    color: white;
    padding-left: 20%;
    width: 79%;
    height: 15px;
    float:
}
```

Default.aspx

```
 <div id="Header">
    <div style="text-align:center !important">
     <asp:Menu ID="Menu" runat="server" Orientation="Horizontal" >
    <Items>
        <asp:MenuItem Text="MenuItem1" Value="MenuItem1">
            <asp:MenuItem Text="Test1" Value="Test1" />
            <asp:MenuItem Text="Test2" Value="Test2" />
        </asp:MenuItem>
        </Items> 
    </asp:Menu>   
    </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: What is the resulting HTML code (instead of the aspx)?

Comment: Huh, looking at it through IE, i see the   center !important being crossed out...

Comment: Can you modify the style of the `div` right under `#Header`? If you change the style and add `display:inline-block;margin:auto auto;` the menu displays centered on my computer.

Comment: Works wonders.  Now, to figure out what I missed, why didn't the simple `text-align: center;` work in this case?

Comment: The div by default has `display:block` and occupies the 100% of the width; by changing it to `inline-block`, its width will be adjusted to the width of the menu

Answer (score 0):

Asp:Menu alignment depends on "dir" attribute of parent element which is "ltr" by default.
Set dir="rtl" attribute on a parent element for asp:Menu right alignment, for example:

```
<div dir="rtl">
    <asp:Menu>
    </asp:Menu>
</div>
```